# ScrollBar disappears when changing width of relativelayout

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

ok, so i have a radiogroup with a relativelayout with a scrollview with a linearlayout with the RadioButtons. When i change the relativelayout width to move the scrollbar the scrollbar just disappears. See photo below:

[ScrollBar in wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlril.png)

[ScrollBar gone after changed width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cYyl.png)

And in XML form:

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupLang"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textLangHidden"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textLangHidden"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="75dp"
    android:paddingStart="13dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="216dp"
            android:scrollbarSize="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbChinese"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbChinese"
                    android:text="@string/chinese"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbEnglish"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbEnglish"
                    android:text="@string/english"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbFrench"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbFrench"
                    android:text="@string/french"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbJapanese"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbJapanese"
                    android:text="@string/japanese"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbKorean"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbKorean"
                    android:text="@string/korean"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbRussian"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbRussian"
                    android:text="@string/russian"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbSpanish"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbSpainsh"
                    android:text="@string/spanish"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rbSwedish"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="rbSwedish"
                    android:text="@string/swedish"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

If anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this part:

```
android:paddingEnd="75dp"
```

...to something like:

```
android:paddingEnd="5dp"
```

The RadioGroup is limited to:

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
```

The bar becomes invisible "behind" the margin since the RelativeLayout, Scrollview etc. is limited to 170dp. 170dp + 75dp = 245dp. The last 45dp become invisible. The margin is 10dp.